# Why Asp.Net MVC 5 put @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") at the bottom in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I put `<script>` blocks which use jQuery in the body of one (and only one) cshtml file which uses the template and they causes error because jQuery is not loaded yet.

What's the point to put the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml file?

The bottom of the `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The following shows the generated source of the cshtml file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { /// $ not defined.
        // .....
    });
</script>

    <hr />
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use sections :

in your layout :

```
...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
...
```

in yours cshtml :

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { /// $ not defined.
            // .....
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: just for clarification.  Note that the scripts have been rendered before the section you are about to call.  Hence, everything called within this section will have access to all these scripts.

Answer (score 10):

Just enclose it inside `section scripts` in .cshtml Page as shown.

```
@section scripts{
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    // .....
  });
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice to load your javascript files after every possible HTML element.

Knowing this, I would place your document ready handler after loading all libs.

```
 <hr />
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { /// $ not defined.
        // .....
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But I just need to insert the `<script>` block just in one page (a cshtml file use the template). Modify the `Layout.cshtml` will affect all the pages use the template.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is at the top of the page, and there are problems then it may cause the page to stop/take a long time loading.  Putting them at the bottom allows the page the render fully before your scripting goes to work.